# Vue JS | Переопределение функций заложенных в установленном пакете из npm (node modules)

Tags: vue.js, npm

Для установки какого-то готового пакета из npm , возникло желание переопределить значения заложенные в нём, к примеру имеется пакет - [@alfsnd/vue-bootstrap-select](http://github.com/Sandalf/vue-bootstrap-select)

При включении поиска в select

```
<v-select :searchable="true" />
```

появляется input для сортировки элементов по внесённым данным, собственно вопрос заключается в том, что placeholder в этом input'e содержит английские буквы (Search) , хотелось бы перевести его на русский или просто задать свои какие-то свойства.

Как можно переопределить значения самого пакета не трогая папку node_modules (потому-что не рекомендуется там вообще что-то менять).

Конечно есть вариант изменить в самом пакете значения, но есть ли возможность не делать этого в папке node_modules чтобы не разрушать целостность изначального пакета?

По пути:

> /node_modules/@alfsnd/vue-bootstrap-select/src/vue-bootstrap-select.vue

Содержится необходимый компонент для изменения, в нём есть строчка:

```
props: {
    labelSearchPlaceholder: {
        type: String,
        default: "Search"
    },
},
```

Как можно изменить эту переменную на свою в своём компоненте который подключает пакет

> import VSelect from '@alfsnd/vue-bootstrap-select'

Дублирую вопрос коротко:

- Как можно переопределить значения заложенные в пакете установленном через npm?

Comment: первое что пришло в голову - форкнуть пакет, собрать со своими изменениями и использовать. Только поддерживать придётся. Но вообще вопрос любопытный.

Comment: @AK ну так это и понятно, такой способ имеет место быть как и простое изменение через node_modules , но мне кажется существует и переопределение, но мой мозг отказывается находить информацию по этой бредовой идее :<

Comment: Вам сюда https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В поле `props` задаются возможные свойства компонента, которые могут быть установлены снаружи. Как можно заметить в примере

```
labelSearchPlaceholder: {
    type: String,
    default: "Search"
},
```

указывается тип свойства и его значение по умолчанию.

Чтобы указать свое значение достаточно передать его как и любое другое через атрибут, например:

```
<v-select :searchable="true" :labelSearchPlaceholder="fieldWithCustomSeacrh"/>
<v-select :searchable="true" labelSearchPlaceholder="custom seacrh string"/>
```

***[Рабочий пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/82kqm5kr8l)***

Comment: это не то. Насколько я понял, речь идет о том, чтобы имя переменной "labelSearchPlaceholder"  поменять на что-то другое.

Comment: @Дмытрык, _собственно вопрос заключается в том, что placeholder в этом input'e содержит английские буквы (Search) , хотелось бы перевести его на русский_

Comment: Точно, согласен...

Comment: Все верно, это подходит для решения проблемы, но можно ли изменять параметр в camelCase а не kebab-case? По-сути если работает через кебаб, то как-то и через camel должно, но как??

Comment: @MoloF, не понял вопроса

Comment: @Grundy , вы вписали значение в сам тег компонента, то есть - **<v-select :labelSearchPlaceholder="fieldWithCustomSeacrh"/>** . А можно ли это перенести в сам код что находится ниже, где происходит импорт и настройка компонента ниже. То есть я устанавливаю пакет через npm, далее создаю свой компонент и подгружаю пакет через import и соответственно настраиваю работу своего компонента дальше в коде. Я знаю что есть kebab-case в котором параметры передаются в сам тег подобно тому что вы написали, и через camel-case в коде между <script></script> .

Comment: @MoloF, kebab и camel - это совсем другое, а не то, что ты говоришь. Но я не совсем понимаю что именно ты хочешь в итоге. Ты хочешь получить сам компонент в коде и в коде свойство устанавливать без использования каких-либо атрибутов? Но в примере у тебя атрибут `searchable` - его ты тоже хочешь убрать из разметки? Не совсем понятно в чем цель этого

Comment: @Grundy , как заменить значение у переменной так, чтобы не писать в теге ничего, а чтобы он принялся ко всем остальным. У меня  имеется 3 селекта для выборки, каждый select идет в зависимости от другого, то есть через ajax подгружаются данные. Собственно говоря мне приходится вписывать все эти дополнительные параметы в теги, вместо того чтобы задать это один раз. В самом подключаемом компоненте по дефолту стоит отключение поиска у элемента select, а мне необходимо его переопределить, в этом и заключалась тема, чтобы переопределить дефолтные значения подключаемого компонента

Comment: @MoloF, а данном случае похоже никак не изменить, так как строки жестко забиты. Однако можно сделать свой [компонент расширяющий данный](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#extends) и переписать в нем это свойство так, как нужно.